# How to create a Payment Forecast Profile in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table with a number of header records, how can I use SQL to generate insert statements that
will populate another table with a projected forecast profile for each customer based on the term but
restricted to the start date and end date. For example Customer ID 2255689 should have a projected
profile as shown.

[image]

```
  1/11/2020 = 210,000
  1/02/2021 = 210,000
  1/05/2021 = 210,000
  1/08/2021 = 210,000

  1/11/2021 = 210,000
  1/02/2022 = 210,000
  1/05/2022 = 210,000
  1/08/2022 = 210,000

  1/11/2022 = 210,000
  1/02/2023 = 210,000
  1/05/2023 = 210,000
  1/08/2023 = 210,000
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I’ve tried using a while loop inside a cte with no luck, I refuse to use a cursor as it’s generally frowned upon due to performance issues.

Comment: The usual solution for generating a list of dates is the recursive CTE.

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a **Recursive CTE** within table function to generate the **installments dates** and call it with cross apply.

```
CREATE FUNCTION utfInstallements (
    @start_date DATETIME
    ,@end_date DATETIME
    ,@increments INT
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH AllDays AS (
        SELECT @start_date AS [Date]
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, @increments, [Date])
        FROM AllDays
        WHERE [Date] < DATEADD(MONTH, - 1 * @increments, @end_date)
        )

SELECT [Date]
FROM AllDays
GO
```

Call it using:

```
SELECT C.customer_id
    ,C.start_date
    ,C.end_date
    ,C.term
    ,C.amount
    ,P.DATE AS 'Installment Date'
FROM contracts C
CROSS APPLY utfInstallements(C.start_date, C.end_date, 12 / term) P
WHERE C.customer_id = 2255689
```

***Result is :***

```
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| customer_id | start_date              | end_date                | term | amount | Installment Date        |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2021-11-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2022-05-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2022-11-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2023-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
```

If you want one table for all customers:

```
SELECT C.customer_id
    ,C.start_date
    ,C.end_date
    ,C.term
    ,C.amount
    ,P.DATE AS 'Installment Date'
FROM contracts C
CROSS APPLY utfInstallements(C.start_date, C.end_date, 12 / term) P
ORDER BY C.customer_id
```

***The result is:***

```
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| customer_id | start_date              | end_date                | term | amount | Installment Date        |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2019-06-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2019-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2019-10-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2019-12-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2020-04-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2022-04-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2022-10-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2022-12-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2023-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2023-10-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2023-12-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2024-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2024-04-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2024-06-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2024-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 1369754     | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 6    | 135000 | 2024-10-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2021-11-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2022-05-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2022-11-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2255689     | 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 4    | 210000 | 2023-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------+--------+-------------------------+
```